# ¿Formatear una lista en Python?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista en Python, que puede ir cambiando según los datos que ponga el usuario:

```
Dialer = [1,9,2,'.',1,6,8,'.',0,'.',2,6]
```

Al imprimir la lista obtengo esto:

> [1, 9, 2, '.', 1, 6, 8, '.', 0, '.', 2, 6]

¿Cómo puedo formatear la lista para obtener al final algo así?:

> 192.168.0.26

Al mismo tiempo, ¿Cómo puedo guardar esto en una variable? Algo así:

```
Cadena = '192.168.0.26'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu lista es de strings:

```
dialer = ['1','9','2','.','1','6','8','.','0','.','2','6']
cadena = "".join(dialer)

print(cadena)
```

> "192.168.0.26"

Si tu lista contiene enteros y/o strings debes pasar cada entero dentro de la lista a str. Puedes hacerlo con un for pero como ya te lo comentaron de esa forma lo haré con `map`

```
dialer = [1, 9, 2, '.', 1, 6, 8, '.', 0, '.', 2, 6]
cadena = "".join(map(str, dialer))

print(cadena)
```

> '192.168.0.26'

Comment: No se entiende lo que significa ese código.

Comment: Lo mismo que el de arriba pero sin usar un for que no es necesario

Comment: ¿y el join para qué sirve?

Comment: En las listas el join une cada valor del interior de la lista por lo que especifiques. por ejemplo, si tengo a= [0, 2, 3, 4] y coloco " ".join(a) me devolvera: "0 2 3 4" entre espacios por que es como especifique. En los strings funciona por cada caracter

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo tengo que agregar los números como caracteres en lugar de enteros para que funcione de forma correcta!

Comment: Tienes razon. De hecho tenia asumido que la lista era de strings por eso lo puse de esa forma, sino seria con un for como hizo el user de abajo. Cosas que pasan cuando comentas con la cabeza mal. Ya arregle por si otro necesita

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas haces es asignar la lista, luego recorrerla aplicando un join

```
Dialer = [1,9,2,'.',1,6,8,'.',0,'.',2,6]
str2 = "".join(str(x) for x in Dialer)
print(str2)
192.168.0.26 // salida
```

Eso debería funcionar

Comment: Edité tu respuesta para que el código se viera de una mejor manera, le agregué los paréntesis al `print(str2)` porque veo que el está usando `python` > 3.x y desde dicha versión los pide, la probé de forma local y funcionó! espero sea marcada como respuesta.

Comment: Efectivamente había que usar los paréntesis, yo la probé en python 2.x. Muchas gracias por la edición.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Comment: ¿Te funcionó alguna de las respuestas? De ser así, no te olvides de calificarla, así esa respuesta se ubica más arriba y es más fácil para otros usuarios identificarla.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución más fácil y entendible es:

```
Dialer = [1,9,2,'.',1,6,8,'.',0,'.',2,6]
Cadena = ""
for i in Dialer:
    Cadena = Cadena + str(i) # donde i va a ser cada elemento de Dialer
print(Cadena) # imprimo la lista y ya está guardada en una variable también
```